# Border around first half of the ordered list

Tags: html, css

I need to display Terms and Conditions as HTML on a web page. As seen in the below screenshot I need to create borders around sections of the terms and conditions that need to be signed. The problem is I don't know how to create this border (first one in screenshot) so that it wraps around the area I need.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!-- MORE HTML ELEMENTS ABOVE -->

<li class="parent"><strong>CTU's Rights and Obligations</strong>
    <ol>
        <li class="child"><strong>CTU</strong> will offer the <strong>Student</strong> tutor-facilitated and/or virtual instructor-led and/or <strong>Blended Tuition</strong> in the year for the <strong>Programme</strong>.</li>
        <li class="child border-end">The <strong>Parties</strong> acknowledge that <strong>CTU</strong> provides facilitator-led tuition and therefore:
            <ol>
                <li class="sub-child">in the event of resignation or sickness or temporary indisposition of a facilitator, classes may become disrupted and be rescheduled;</li>
                <li class="sub-child">in the event of a permanent indisposition of the facilitator, <strong>CTU</strong> shall within reasonable time constraints, once the permanent indisposition has been confirmed, engage the services of another facilitator; and</li>
                <li class="sub-child"><strong>CTU</strong> shall not be liable for any disruption or rescheduling of classes due to a facilitator's personal indisposition.</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Provisional timetables for the year shall be made available to the Student at the time of the commencement of the Student's Programmes. CTU reserves the right at, any time, to alter the timetables, with adequate notice being given to the Student, where reasonably possible. No other commitments should be made by the Student prior to receiving the schedule.</li>
        <li>Subject to <strong>CTU's</strong> rights to cancel any <strong>Programme</strong> on the terms and conditions set out hereunder, this <strong>Form</strong> constitutes an undertaking on the side of the <strong>Student</strong> to receive the tuition, participate in the <strong>Programme</strong> enrolled for and for the <strong>Student</strong> and/or the <strong>Parent/Guardian</strong> to pay the <strong>Programme Fees</strong> in full, as and when the <strong>Fees</strong> become due and payable.
        </li>
    </ol>

    <!-- MORE HTML ELEMENTS BELOW -->

</li>
```

**Things I have tried:**

**1. Border around parent**

```
// Doesnt work, border is around whole ordered list
.parent {
    border:1px solid
}
```

**2. Border around parent and children**

```
// Works for top border, but not sure how to get left & right border
.parent {
    border-top:1px solid black;
}
// Kind of works, not sure how to extend borders
.border-end {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**3. Using pseudo elements**

This seems to be the best solution so far but its not 100% yet. Problem is the height of the text might differ so not too sure how not to hard-code the width and height. [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/jd70pys3/) of the below:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.parent:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 110%;
    background: #000;
    top: 0;
    left: -5%;
}
.border-end {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.border-end:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 115%;
    background: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -10%;
}
.border-end:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 136%;
    width: 1px;
    background: #000;
    top: -37%;
    left: -10%;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will have to wrap those part which needs to be inside the box with a `div`. I don't think its possible by just taking `ol` or `li` into account since first boxing scheme seems very hybrid.

Comment: @Saharsh thanx, makes sense what you say, but is a DIV a valid element inside ul and ol?

Comment: Yep! It is a valid element

Comment: Awesome, this might be a great solution then, I will quickly test it, thanx!

Comment: I have posted a solution with same idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with so much tweeks.

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid black
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none
}

ol.parent {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  counter-reset: item;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  padding: 0 30px;
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: item;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
.child:before {
  content: counter(item) ". ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
}

.border-side {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<li class="wrapper"><strong>CTU's Rights and Obligations</strong>
  <ol class="parent">
    <li class="child border-side"><strong>CTU</strong> will offer the <strong>Student</strong> tutor-facilitated and/or virtual instructor-led and/or <strong>Blended Tuition</strong> in the year for the <strong>Programme</strong>.</li>
    <li class="child border-side border-bottom">The <strong>Parties</strong> acknowledge that <strong>CTU</strong> provides facilitator-led tuition and therefore:
      <ol>
        <li class="sub-child">in the event of resignation or sickness or temporary indisposition of a facilitator, classes may become disrupted and be rescheduled;</li>
        <li class="sub-child">in the event of a permanent indisposition of the facilitator, <strong>CTU</strong> shall within reasonable time constraints, once the permanent indisposition has been confirmed, engage the services of another facilitator; and</li>
        <li class="sub-child"><strong>CTU</strong> shall not be liable for any disruption or rescheduling of classes due to a facilitator's personal indisposition.</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="child">Provisional timetables for the year shall be made available to the Student at the time of the commencement of the Student's Programmes. CTU reserves the right at, any time, to alter the timetables, with adequate notice being given to the Student,
      where reasonably possible. No other commitments should be made by the Student prior to receiving the schedule.</li>
    <li class="child border">Subject to <strong>CTU's</strong> rights to cancel any <strong>Programme</strong> on the terms and conditions set out hereunder, this <strong>Form</strong> constitutes an undertaking on the side of the <strong>Student</strong> to receive the tuition,
      participate in the <strong>Programme</strong> enrolled for and for the <strong>Student</strong> and/or the <strong>Parent/Guardian</strong> to pay the <strong>Programme Fees</strong> in full, as and when the <strong>Fees</strong> become due and
      payable.
    </li>
  </ol>

  <!-- MORE HTML ELEMENTS BELOW -->

</li>
```

Comment: Yes! This solution is solid! Thanx @Akhi Akl appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into using the `nth-child` selectors. I've created the below example, which highlights the second `li` and all its children. It's just the case of adding more selectors to highlight the options you require.

```css
.parent ol li:nth-child(3n-1) {
  border:1px solid black;
}

.sub-child {
  border:none!important;
}
```

```html
<li class="parent"><strong>CTU's Rights and Obligations</strong>
    <ol>
        <li class="child"><strong>CTU</strong> will offer the <strong>Student</strong> tutor-facilitated and/or virtual instructor-led and/or <strong>Blended Tuition</strong> in the year for the <strong>Programme</strong>.</li>
        <li class="child border-end">The <strong>Parties</strong> acknowledge that <strong>CTU</strong> provides facilitator-led tuition and therefore:
            <ol>
                <li class="sub-child">in the event of resignation or sickness or temporary indisposition of a facilitator, classes may become disrupted and be rescheduled;</li>
                <li class="sub-child">in the event of a permanent indisposition of the facilitator, <strong>CTU</strong> shall within reasonable time constraints, once the permanent indisposition has been confirmed, engage the services of another facilitator; and</li>
                <li class="sub-child"><strong>CTU</strong> shall not be liable for any disruption or rescheduling of classes due to a facilitator's personal indisposition.</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Provisional timetables for the year shall be made available to the Student at the time of the commencement of the Student's Programmes. CTU reserves the right at, any time, to alter the timetables, with adequate notice being given to the Student, where reasonably possible. No other commitments should be made by the Student prior to receiving the schedule.</li>
        <li>Subject to <strong>CTU's</strong> rights to cancel any <strong>Programme</strong> on the terms and conditions set out hereunder, this <strong>Form</strong> constitutes an undertaking on the side of the <strong>Student</strong> to receive the tuition, participate in the <strong>Programme</strong> enrolled for and for the <strong>Student</strong> and/or the <strong>Parent/Guardian</strong> to pay the <strong>Programme Fees</strong> in full, as and when the <strong>Fees</strong> become due and payable.
        </li>
    </ol>

    <!-- MORE HTML ELEMENTS BELOW -->

</li>
```

Comment: Great answer this one is really close and I like that you are using nth-child selectors, but the border needs to be around the heading as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```css
.border-start {
         border-top: solid black;
         border-left: solid black;
         border-right: solid black;}
.border-middle {
         border-left: solid black;
         border-right: solid black;}
.border-end {
         border-bottom: solid black;
         border-left: solid black;
         border-right: solid black;}
```

```html
<li><strong>CTU's Rights and Obligations</strong>
    <ol>
        <li class="border-start"><strong>CTU</strong> will offer the <strong>Student</strong> tutor-facilitated and/or virtual instructor-led and/or <strong>Blended Tuition</strong> in the year for the <strong>Programme</strong>.</li>
        <li class="border-end">The <strong>Parties</strong> acknowledge that <strong>CTU</strong> provides facilitator-led tuition and therefore:
            <ol>
                <li>in the event of resignation or sickness or temporary indisposition of a facilitator, classes may become disrupted and be rescheduled;</li>
                <li>in the event of a permanent indisposition of the facilitator, <strong>CTU</strong> shall within reasonable time constraints, once the permanent indisposition has been confirmed, engage the services of another facilitator; and</li>
                <li><strong>CTU</strong> shall not be liable for any disruption or rescheduling of classes due to a facilitator's personal indisposition.</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Provisional timetables for the year shall be made available to the Student at the time of the commencement of the Student's Programmes. CTU reserves the right at, any time, to alter the timetables, with adequate notice being given to the Student, where reasonably possible. No other commitments should be made by the Student prior to receiving the schedule.</li>
        <li>Subject to <strong>CTU's</strong> rights to cancel any <strong>Programme</strong> on the terms and conditions set out hereunder, this <strong>Form</strong> constitutes an undertaking on the side of the <strong>Student</strong> to receive the tuition, participate in the <strong>Programme</strong> enrolled for and for the <strong>Student</strong> and/or the <strong>Parent/Guardian</strong> to pay the <strong>Programme Fees</strong> in full, as and when the <strong>Fees</strong> become due and payable.
        </li>
    </ol>

    <!-- MORE HTML ELEMENTS BELOW -->

</li>
```

With li{list-style-position:inside;} you have the numbers inside the borders aswell

Comment: This is also a great solution, only thing is the border needs to be around the bold heading as well. Thats whats causing my headaches :)

Answer (score 0):

Try simpler way:

```css
.bordered {
  border:1px solid black
}

.bordered-no-top {
  border-top:none
}

.bordered-no-bottom{
  border-bottom:none
}
```

```html
<li class="parent"><strong>CTU's Rights and Obligations</strong>
    <ol>
        <li class="child bordered bordered-no-bottom"><strong>CTU</strong> will offer the <strong>Student</strong> tutor-facilitated and/or virtual instructor-led and/or <strong>Blended Tuition</strong> in the year for the <strong>Programme</strong>.</li>
        <li class="child bordered bordered-no-top">The <strong>Parties</strong> acknowledge that <strong>CTU</strong> provides facilitator-led tuition and therefore:
            <ol>
                <li class="sub-child">in the event of resignation or sickness or temporary indisposition of a facilitator, classes may become disrupted and be rescheduled;</li>
                <li class="sub-child">in the event of a permanent indisposition of the facilitator, <strong>CTU</strong> shall within reasonable time constraints, once the permanent indisposition has been confirmed, engage the services of another facilitator; and</li>
                <li class="sub-child"><strong>CTU</strong> shall not be liable for any disruption or rescheduling of classes due to a facilitator's personal indisposition.</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Provisional timetables for the year shall be made available to the Student at the time of the commencement of the Student's Programmes. CTU reserves the right at, any time, to alter the timetables, with adequate notice being given to the Student, where reasonably possible. No other commitments should be made by the Student prior to receiving the schedule.</li>
        <li class="bordered">Subject to <strong>CTU's</strong> rights to cancel any <strong>Programme</strong> on the terms and conditions set out hereunder, this <strong>Form</strong> constitutes an undertaking on the side of the <strong>Student</strong> to receive the tuition, participate in the <strong>Programme</strong> enrolled for and for the <strong>Student</strong> and/or the <strong>Parent/Guardian</strong> to pay the <strong>Programme Fees</strong> in full, as and when the <strong>Fees</strong> become due and payable.
        </li>
    </ol>

    <!-- MORE HTML ELEMENTS BELOW -->

</li>
```

Comment: Looks good, but same as the other answers, the border needs to be around the heading as well :(

Comment: I know the design is beautiful. But if an element was bordered, its chills must be bordered. @Chris

Comment: If you still want to make interface like design, I suggest you use ```div``` instead ```ol/ul li```. set width of all ```divs``` is full, each ```div``` contains an indent ```div``` and content ```div```. Then you can use ```bordered```, ```bordered-no-bottom```, ```bordered-no-top``` to customize style.

Comment: Thanx i will test this solution as well